# Delete entered password in hidden password prompt (Linux) with shortcut

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, passwords

Is there a way to delete all characters that I entered in a hidden password prompt in Linux? For example, when I SSH to a server, it asks for my password where the entered keys are not shown:

```
$ ssh root@somehost
root@somehost's password:
```

Is there a way to delete all my entered text without having to press backspace for an unknown amount of time? When I think I entered something wrong I want to start over and pressing backspace for a few seconds is annoying. I tried <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to hopefully select the whole text and <kbd>Home</kbd>. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> cancels the whole command and I have to send the command again to retry. This is almost the best and fastest solution but still not satisfying. Insert does not work in my shell either.

Comment: Regarding Ctrl+A, in the terminal this usually means "go to start of line". The set of keys used in the terminal (especially bash) is often closer to Emacs than to Windows.

Comment: Sshing as root is generally considered a very very bad practice.

Comment: To delete characters from the screen, you will need to use cursor control sequences (if your terminal supports them). By running `ssh` from a script, you can analyse the parameter string before you run it.

Comment: Please pay attention to what @Sam told. You should disable root logins everywhere. Log in as a regular user with a complicated password and then `su` to become root. The next step is to disable password-based authentication schemes in SSH and use keys for login.

Comment: @kostix I'm pretty sure disabling passwords should be the first step. If you are using passwords, then with su and disabled root, it's just a matter of entering the password which the attacker already guessed a second time after login, so you only gain something if the user name is hard to guess (which it often isn't, I assume without having statistics). And without password login it adds a second secret, the password, but this is worth less than the private key which is a longer secret.

Comment: @Sam I remember I had an installation once where I bypassed my router and enabled root access via ssh with a dictionary password. Within a couple weeks, someone online had hijacked my PC. You live, you learn...

Comment: @Sam: Not with public key authentication (and passwords disabled).

Answer (score 160, accepted):

You can delete the entire typed password with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>.

Comment: This also works in the regular terminal prompt too!

Comment: For reference, this is the default key-binding in readline's "emacs mode" for `unix-line-discard`, described as "Kill backward from the cursor to the beginning of the current line." Ref: https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html#SEC17 GNU readline is the input library used by most shells and many other interactive programs (but is *not* built into the tty, so this won't work *everywhere*).

Comment: @IMSoP However, Ctrl-U itself *is* built into the tty (as the default character for the `stty kill` function), which is why it works with the ssh password prompt.

Comment: BTW, Ctrl+K is the equivalent for deleting from the cursor to the *end* of the line.

Comment: A minor note is that some GUI programs also try to play nicely with us the old farts and implement support for `C-u` in their prompts. As one example, the `i3lock` program allows hitting `C-u` to zap the invalid input.

Comment: @Random832 Well, you learn something every day. Thanks!

Comment: @IMSoP: I wrote an answer to explain more about why this works, and how it's different from line-editing with `readline` in bash.

Comment: @wjandrea: ctrl+k is readline/emacs only, not something you can do on a POSIX tty in canonical mode.

Comment: Warning: This will only clear everything if your cursor is at the end of what you typed, otherwise incomplete deletes may occur! (For instance because you wanted to change the first character, and then decided to clear everything).

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: That's not possible, ssh doesn't use readline to provide line-editing.  See my answer.

Answer (score 14):

**Unlike `bash`, `ssh`'s password prompt doesn't use any special terminal-input library like `readline`.**  The line-editing features are just the baseline POSIX TTY line-editing features.

So you have a POSIX TTY in "cooked" mode (not raw), aka canonical mode, and the only line editing that's available is what's provided by the kernel.  See [`stty(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html), and notice that
**`kill = ^U`**.  This is also where the backspace character is defined (`erase = ^?`).  Word-erase (`^W`) is convenient when you're not typing blind.

`lnext = ^V` means you can type control-v then anything (including control-c) to get a literal control-c.

**To debug what you were trying to do blindly, run `cat` or `cat > /dev/null` in your terminal**.  Type stuff, then see what works and what doesn't to edit it.

---

`readline` (used by `bash`) reads raw character and does the line-editing in user-space.  Its default bindings are compatible with the default TTY control characters, though, for the subset of editing features that they both provide.

readline goes way beyond the simple line editing of a plain TTY.  (e.g. a TTY can only delete characters at the end of the line, so there's no `^a` and `delete` or left/right arrow)

When `bash` runs a command in the foreground, it puts the TTY into canonical mode first (because that's the default).  So running `stty -a` (with no redirection) will always see its own terminal in canonical mode.  But if you redirect input from some other TTY that has `bash` running on it, you can see what terminal settings bash + readline applied.  e.g. `stty -a < /dev/pts/12` shows `-icanon` for raw mode because I have a `bash` running on that terminal.  (I switched to another tab and ran `tty`, then used that device file path from the first terminal).  If I ran `cat` in that other terminal, I'd see `icanon` for canonical mode.

Related: [The TTY demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/)

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Canonical-or-Not.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_terminal_interface

Comment: You can actually just type 'stty' to see all the current settings. Using 'stty rows ##' or 'stty cols ##' will let you change on the Fly how many rows or columns the terminal window has available to it. Which is especially handy when you're working in a window in a window through something like VNC which doesn't necessarily catch how big your exterior window is properly. You can basically Define your active area to be smaller than the window it's in and then not have to scroll around. Allowing VI and other things to still work properly. It can also remap backspace and delete on the Fly.

Comment: @RowanHawkins: my last paragraph was poorly edited.  Fixed now.  I was trying to make the point that by redirecting from another tty, you can see the `stty` / ioctl settings that bash+readline itself has applied in raw mode.  (And the fact that it's in raw mode at all, where most of the special characters don't apply)